# JavaScript Error when adding Submit Email field

Tags: sitecore-forms

When I add a Sitecore Form to a page via the Experience Editor that has a "Submit email" type field I get a JavaScript error that breaks the experience editor. I then have to remove the form from the page via the content editor. I can also go into the form designer and remove the "submit email" field, save the form, and that will prevent the error. I need this field though to tell the form where to send the content. The error in the console says that it is in the ConfigureOptimizationStrip.js file located at http://my-domain/-/speak/v1/ribbon/ConfigureOptimizationStrip.js. Unfortunately, I don't think this file is a part of my project and is instead a part of Sitecore. Has anyone else experienced this issue or know how to fix it?

[image]

Here is the script for the SubmitEmail.cshtml:

```
@model Foundation.Forms.Models.SubmitEmailViewModel
<input id="@Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value)" name="@Html.NameFor(m => Model.Value)" type="hidden" value="@Model.EmailAddress" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hiddenField = document.getElementById(@Html.Raw("\"" + Html.IdFor(m => Model.Value) + "\""));
    var parent = hiddenField.parentNode;
    if (parent.classList.contains("sc-formdesign-fieldcontainer")) {
        var textDiv = document.createElement("div");
        textDiv.innerHTML = "(Hidden submit email field)";
        parent.appendChild(textDiv);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the ootb "Send Email Campaign Message" submit action? Or an email field? "Submit email" does sound custom..  can you show us that item in Sitecore?

Comment: I just looked and it is a custom field type. I updated the original question with a screenshot and the code from the view.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. When this was created the variable, "parent" already exists in scope so this code is changing that variable and causing the error.